# Kubespray gives fatal "module (kube) is missing interpreter line" error

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

While installation of Kubernetes cluster with Kubespray 2.22.0 on RHEL 8, I get the following error on the master node where I run ansible-playbook:

**fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "module (kube) is missing interpreter line"}**

Is there anyone to help me?

I bypassed the symlink inside the ./library/kube.py by changing the library path as ./plugins/modules in the ansible.cfg. I also copied the ./plugins/modules/kube.py to ./library/ without changing the path but none of these changes worked